# Add Codec using fluent ffmpeg without converting it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file, ffmpeg

Is there a way to add codec to my file without needing to convert it? My file is already ogg at this point so I just need the opus codec.

That's what I have:

```
export async function addCodec(input: Readable, output: PassThrough) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg(input)
      .format("ogg")
      .audioCodec("libopus")
      .on("error", (err) => {
        error("An error occurred: " + err.message);
        reject(false);
      })
      .on("progress", (progress) => {})
      .on("end", (res) => {
        log("ON END", res);
        log("Processing finished !");
        resolve(true);
      })
      .writeToStream(output);
  });
}
```

I've tried other libs like prism-media but it didn't work and also already tried removing the format() but it leads to an error.